# How to enable client side validation in Bootstrap modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I work on app which have bootstrap modal(for sign in/registration) where **client side validation** is performed. When you try to sign in with regular, but non existing email in db, **server side validation** is performed and you are redirected to users/signin page.

So, instead of that redirection, I need to make validations on client side and show error message in modal. Problem is, I work on real, big app for first time and I cant find place where those validations and redirections are performed. I can't find any relevant JS file or controller actions..

User model:

```
  validates :password, presence: true, :on => :create
  validates :password, confirmation: true, :on => :create
  validates :email, presence: true
  validates :username, uniqueness: true, presence: true
  validates_format_of :username, :with  => /^[a-z\d]*$/, :message => "Just letters and numbers please"
```

Modal for registration:

```
#modal-registration.modal.hide.fade{"aria-hidden" => "true", "aria-labelledby" => "registrationLabel", role: "dialog", tabindex: "-1"}
  .modal-header
    %button.close{"aria-hidden" => "true", "data-dismiss" => "modal", type: "button"} ×
    %h3#myModalLabel Registration
  .modal-body
    .row-fluid
      .span6
        = simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), html: { class: "form", id: "registration-form" }, :validate => true) do |f|
          .control-group
            .controls
              = f.input :email, autofocus: true, label: false, placeholder: 'email'
          .control-group
            .controls
              = f.input :username, autofocus: true, label: false, placeholder: 'Username'
          .control-group
            .controls
              = f.input :password, label: false, placeholder: 'Password'
          .control-group
            .controls
              = f.input :password_confirmation, label: false, placeholder: 'Password confirmation'
          .control-group
            .controls
              = f.button :submit, "Registration"
      .span6
        = link_to "Registration via Facebook", "#", class: "btn btn-large btn-block"
        = link_to "Registration via LinkedIn", "#", class: "btn btn-large btn-block"
  .modal-footer
    %button.btn{"aria-hidden" => "true", "data-dismiss" => "modal"} Close
```

Client_side_validation jQuery:

```
jQuery ->
  $("#modal-registration, #modal-sign-in").on "shown", ->
    $(ClientSideValidations.selectors.forms).validate()
```

Used gems: devise, client_side_validations, client_side_validations_simple_form, bootstrap, haml.

Comment: try http://jqueryvalidation.org/....will love it

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [rails bootstrap forms](https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/rails-bootstrap-forms) gem?

You can do client side validations with rails bootstrap forms gem easily

You only need to add `remote: true` code, for example:

```
= bootstrap_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :remote => true) do |f|
  = f.email_field :email
  = f.text_field :username
  = f.password_field :password
  = f.password_field :password_confirmation
  = f.submit
```

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I haven't found this to work out of the box at all...